# Is the exponential Shannon entropy sub-additive?

Tags: portfolio-management, mathematics

In a recent paper of Salazar et al. (2014),  [*The Diversification Delta: A Different Perspective*](http://apo.org.au/files/Resource/the_diversification_delta_-_a_different_perspective.pdf), forthcoming in the Journal of Portfolio Management , the authors propose to use the exponential Shannon entropy as an uncertainty measure in portfolio selection and make the following claim:

If we define $$H(X)=−\int_xf(x)\text{ln}f(x)dx$$ 
to be the differential Shannon entropy, then we have that for random variables $X$ and $Y$ (pp.10): $$\text{exp}(H(X+Y))\leqslant \text{exp}(H(X))+\text{exp}(H(X))$$  After thorough research I haven't been able to find any proof of this sub-additive property which makes me wonder: is this property really correct? And would you have any proof of it? Moreover is seems that this sub-additive property is at odds with the entropy power inequality that says that for independent $X$ and $Y$: $$\text{exp}(2H(X+Y))⩾\text{exp}(2H(X))+\text{exp}(2H(X))$$

Also, I am interested in knowing how this property would generalize to Rényi entropy defined as $$H_\alpha(X)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\text{ln}∫_x(f(x))^αdx$$ Is $\text{exp}(H_\alpha(X))$ also sub-additive for some values of $\alpha$?

I would really appreciate any insights you might have on this problem.

Comment: how well does the **DD* portfolio** even work out-of-sample? Do the optimal weights it finds in-sample remain near optimal out-of-sample? in modern portfolio theory, the **max Sharpe portfolio** often results in worse performance out-of-sample because it has to estimate the asset means for an input, which are difficult to estimate, whereas the **minimum variance portfolio** is more consistent out-of-sample as its in-sample estimate because it only requires variance for an input. The DD*, however, uses neither variance nor asset means for inputs, but instead, asset and portfolio entropy.